# Can't reach home networked Linux computer, but it's up and has internet access, not sure how to trouble shoot

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, raspberry-pi

I have a home server set up on a Raspberry Pi running Dietpi / Debian. Everything worked fine and I provided several services to the home network, e.g. Paperless. The server has a static IP, which I use to address it.

Now I bridged internet from the Wifi to the Ethernet port using iptables and route. This also works fine.

However, after a while the home server becomes inaccessible from the local network, including for SSH. When I reboot everything works fine for a while, then access breaks again.

I'm struggling to know how to trouble shoot, and would appreciate help.

The output of `sudo route` looks like this:

```
Destination  Gateway       Genmask        Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
default      ttrouter.lan  0.0.0.0        UG    0      0     0 wlan0
172.18.0.0   0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0    U     0      0     0 br-a3fec4c9c565
192.168.1.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U     0      0     0 wlan0
192.168.2.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0  U     0      0     0 eth0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `inaccessible from the local network` ... via wifi or ethernet?

Comment: Why are there three subnets in play if the Ethernet and the Wi-Fi are bridged together? Why is it not a single subnet? Why is iptables involved? Are you trying to be a NA[P]T gateway router at the same time as being a bridge for some reason? Also, is the Pi's Wi-Fi interface in AP mode, or is it in client mode connected to a separate AP?

Comment: @JaromandaX - via wifi. The ethernet is connected to my TV, and the Pi provides the wifi internet to the TV via the ethernet port. The TV internet works, as do outgoing connections on the Pi.
@Spiff - not sure, this may be part of the problem? But when I restart the Pi, I _can_ access its services normally (incl SSH), and the `route` output looks the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser, Nick.

Issues that present themselves after some random amount of time can be difficult to diagnose, but there are a few places that you should look first to be able to troubleshoot.

- Some type of power management setting on your server may be disabling the network interface(s). Your configuration may vary, but these tools might produce some helpful results:

> `sudo iwconfig wlan0` - Check power management status on wifi
>
> `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` - Disable if enabled
>
> `sudo ethtool eth0` - For ethernet, look for any power options

- Review the logs, specifically `syslog`, `kern`, `journalctl` and `dmesg`. Pipe these through grep to filter the results. You may have other log files that you can check. Use `-i` with grep for case insensitivity and try some of these keywords: error, timeout, fail, refused, network, wlan0, eth0.

> `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "error"`
>
> `sudo cat /var/log/kern.log`
>
> `dmesg`

- Another device on the network is causing an IP conflict (ZenMap can help identify network devices)
- Overheating (make sure the device is cool)
- Crashing (the log checks will help identify this problem)
- Insufficient resources (monitor with `top` or other service)

You should be able to at least find some more clues as to what might be happening.

Finally, having some type of real-time monitoring while you troubleshoot can help you isolate the relevant logs or events that take place as soon as the issue occurs. You can setup a ping monitor (SmokePing), and/or configure the Pi to send all logs to a collection service on your computer (Rsyslog).

Comment: Thanks @jim-diroff-ii, much appreciated. I will try and mark as solved once I had a chance to try it out.